# Regular expression to split the string after every word

Tags: javascript, regex, join, split

written this string to match all the test strings at once.

```
String="AQuickBrown_fox jump over the-lazy-Dog";
```

Basically I want to make these string look like this:

```
"a-quick-brown-fox-jump-over-the-lazy-dog"
```

I tried `split("/regex/")` function *on string* and applied `join("-")` function *on the returned array* and applied `.toLowerCase()`. But I could not find the solution. I want to know the regular expression that could split the word so that I can get the required string.

Comment: You are expecting the reader to deduce the question from an example. Examples are generally helpful for illustration but they are not a substitute for a precise and unambiguous statement of the question (generally in words alone). The latter represents a skill you will need to become a successful software engineer, where you will need to write code specifications and at least basic documentation, neither of which can be done with examples alone.

Comment: My best friend asks that you change your example to `"AQuickBrown_dog jump over the-lazy-Fox"`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-a-string-into-kebab-case-using-javascript/

This checks for space, capital letters, and underscores. It creates an array and pushes the words that separate the strings. Now join the array with the hyphen using the `join()`. After that convert the whole string into a lower case.

```js
const kebabCase = str => str
    .match(/[A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]*|\b)|[A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]*|[A-Z]|[0-9]+/g)
    .join('-')
    .toLowerCase();

console.log(kebabCase('Geeks For Geeks'));
console.log(kebabCase('GeeksForGeeks'));
console.log(kebabCase('Geeks_For_Geeks'));
console.log(kebabCase('AQuickBrown_fox jump over the-lazy-Dog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer more than one replace for readability

I will purloin the kebabCase name for this

```js
const kebabCase = (str) => str
    // Camelcase - handle single letters too
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])|([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])/g, '$1$3-$2$4') 
    // non-alphanumeric characters and spaces
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-')
    // lowercase and trim dashes
    .toLowerCase().replace(/^-|-$/g, '');


const inputString = "AQuickBrown_fox jump over the-lazy-Dog";
const outputString = kebabCase(inputString);
console.log(outputString);  // "a-quick-brown-fox-jump-over-the-lazy-dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using replace function:

```js
const toKebab = text => text.replace(/[\W_]+|(?<=[A-z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '-').toLowerCase();

console.log(toKebab('AQuickBrown_fox jump over the-lazy-Dog'));
```